# Can a person with a tibia problem become an air traffic controller?

Tags: air-traffic-control

I have a healing tibia. In the worst possible case, if it does not heal fully, will this impede a future attempt to become an air traffic controller?

Comment: In what country?

Answer (score 3):

In the US, an air traffic controller is required to have [Class-II medical](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/app_process/general/classes/). However, [it is mentioned here](https://www.leftseat.com/atc/standard2.htm) that:

> The applicant must have no deformity of spine or limbs of sufficient
>   degree to interfere with the requirements of the position of
>   employment being sought. Certain limitations of range of motion may be
>   acceptable for certain specific options or positions, in which case
>   acceptance for employment will be noted specifically for that position
>   or option only.

Other than the regulatory standpoint, reaching the top air traffic tower might be hard. There may not be elevators reaching all the way to the top. To save space, many use ladders, not even a staircase.

However, working as air traffic controllers does not always mean in the tower. Many radar rooms are ADA complaint and are wheel chair accessible.